# Separating Logic from Design in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

If I were to make a single-window Java program, I have found myself doing something like the following. Note that I tend to do things alot like iOS development.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                               |
|      ExampleJFrame.java              ExampleJPanel.java                       |
|              |                               |                                |
| ExampleJFrameController.java -> ExampleJPanelController.java -> Component(s)  |
|                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I like the way iOS standards are and would like to follow that. This is the closest I can get. My question is if I am doing simple stuff with the `JFrame` such as adding the `JPanel`, setting the title, position, size, etc., should I (1) subclass `JFrame` where that I would only have `ExampleJFrame` and have the object do the aforementioned things to itself or (2) should I only have `ExampleJFrameController` which would create a new `JFrame` and set the title of it and whatnot?

**EDIT**:

With the second option, if I wanted to subclass `ExampleJFrameController`, the parent object would set `JFrame`'s visibility to `true` before the child object can do anything with it. So perhaps I forgot to add an option 3 (which is somewhat implied by the "graphic"): have both `ExampleJFrame` and `ExampleJFrameController`. `ExampleJFrame would set its own size and location and title and`ExampleJFrameController`would set its visibility. Then lies a problem: if`ExampleJFrame`should know about`ExampleJPanel`and`ExampleJFrameController`should know about`ExampleJPanelController`, how would I connect the`ExampleJPanelController`to its`ExampleJPanel`? Or am I missing some details that would resolve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the second option.

Splitting Java code up that far may look really nice and neat, but becomes far too complex when you design Java objects. You end up having dozens of files for something that could easily been done in 3 or 4.

If you went with the first option, every time you wanted to create a new `JFrame`, you would end up creating a new controller. With the second option, you can just add a new object inside of the existing controller class.

Comment: It's also bad OOP style to subclass `JFrame` in such a case instead of just using a JFrame internally. Basically the same problem with people extending Thread instead of implementing Runnable.

Comment: If you need to control the `JFrame` from the `JPanel` implementation, then you would simply call the parent class's object and go from there. If you need to control one `JFrame` from another, then you would need another controller class above (at least to maintain the structure you want).

Answer (score 2):

I think option 2 would be best because you could manage it more easily. Also, you would have the ability to create a new Controller, without having to create a whole new JFrame. This would preserve memory, and would make the program function more efficiently.

Comment: Basically the same as what Jon said :(

Comment: Beat you by a few seconds, but I realized I had missed something from your answer, thanks.

Comment: When mine was 20 seconds ago yours was at "Just now"
But what ev, he will trust yours more